# Weird case of pointer behaviour from void* to unsigned char*

Tags: c++, c

I have a function that takes in a void * buffer as an argument and has to pass it to another function that takes an unsigned char*. Here is the chain of events:

```
unsigned char   data[4];
populate(&data);

void populate (void * buf)
{
...
    unsigned char * datump = ((unsigned char * )buf);
    if ( Unwrap(datump) )
    {...}
}

bool  Unwrap (unsigned char* buf)
{
...
}
```

When I go ahead and do: Unwrap ((unsigned char * )buf), it fails with "No matching function call to Unwrap[(unsigned char*).
But if I use a conversion like I have in the code it works! Why is that?

The problem with that is now I have to do something (help with this too please!) to copy the data from unsigned char * to void *.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see why it shouldn't work with the cast.  That seems odd.

Comment: Try it without the `&` in from of `data`.  `data == &data[0]`.

Comment: Show, in code, the context that fails.  Specify if you are compiling with C or C++.  What is the `[` in "Unwrap[(unsigned char*)", a typo?  What _other_ typos?

Comment: Please share the declaration in the header file. My guess is that it is subtly different from the implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that when you do

```
unsigned char   data[4];
populate(&data);
```

You are passing a `char**` to `populate`. This will cause untold problems when you try to do your conversions (apart from the fact that you are pointing to some random place in memory).

First part to fix:

```
populate(data);
```

The following very simple code compiles and runs just fine:

```
#include <iostream>

bool f1(unsigned char* buf) {
  return true;
}

void populate(void *buf) {
  unsigned char* datump = (unsigned char*) buf;
  if(f1(datump)) std::cout << "it's true!" << std::endl;
}
int main(void) {
  unsigned char data[4];
  populate(data);
}
```

It seems that the fix to the pointer was all that was needed?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should declare `Unwrap` before using it.  `data` is the address of array, `&data[0]` is the address of the first element.  It's equal but with different meaning.

Comment: It is actually declared in a header file.